# Delphi: scroll PageControl tab area to the right

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

After runtime creation of new tabs, I see that last tab is overlapped by system [<] and [>] buttons in the tab header area. How to scroll this area to the rightmost position? Img from one c++ app which looks same as my app. Delphi 7.

[image: tab area]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't select the new created TabSheet you can use [ScrollTabs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomTabControl_ScrollTabs.html) with e.g. PageCount as delta, since the PageControl will scroll as far as possible if the delta exceeds the possible range.

```
   PageControl.ScrollTabs(PageControl.PageCount);
```

If you want to select the created TabSheet and scroll to the rightmost position you just need to set the ActivePageIndex:

```
   PageControl.ActivePageIndex :=  PageControl.PageCount - 1;
```